# UITableViewCell selected by swipe not by tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I'm using RxSwift for binding UITableView to data source. I want to select table cell in table view. Selection does not work by tap, but works well by swipe gesture.  What could be the problem?

That's what I was truing to do:

- update RxSwift, RxCocoa
- clean project
- remove derived data
- try combinations of settings of table view and table view cell

Here my code

*View Model*

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift

class ViewModel {

    let selectItem: AnyObserver<String>
    let didSelectItem: Observable<String>

    let items: Observable<[String]>

    init() {
      let _selectItem = PublishSubject<String>()
      self.selectItem = _selectItem.asObserver()
      self.didSelectItem = _selectItem.asObservable()
      items = TestAppData.getData()
    }
}
```

*ViewController*

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class ViewController: BaseViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var dataTableView: UITableView!

  var viewModel: ViewModel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super .viewDidLoad()
    setup()
  }

  private func setup(){

    viewModel.items
      .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
      .bind(to: dataTableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "DataCell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)) {
        (_, dataValue, cell) in
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataValue
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
      }
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    dataTableView.rx.modelSelected(String.self)
      .bind(to: viewModel.selectItem)
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)
  }
}
```

TableView and TableViewCell settings:
[image]
RxSwift 4.1.2, RxCocoa 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this implementation

```
dataTableView.rx.itemSelected
            .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] indexPath in
                //DO something with cell
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: same problem with this implementation

Comment: @Max `itemSelected` returns `ControlEvent<IndexPath>` so you need to define observer as `var didSelectItem: AnyObserver<IndexPath>`. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: You could also use bind `dataTableView.rx.itemSelected.bind(to: viewModel. didSelectItem).disposed(by: disposeBag)`

Comment: You can use  `modelDeleted(Model.self)`